# How long does it take to brute force Blowfish-448?

Tags: encryption, aes, public-key, brute-force-attack, blowfish

I am conducting an investigation on the efficiency of AES and Blowfish with regards to memory when encrypting data of varying sizes.

I open my essay with an introduction as to what encryption is and the two algorithms I will be discussing.

I have mentioned that AES-256 as $2^{256}$ possible key combinations, and I would like to know how many Blowfish-448 has?

Comment: Well there are 2^448 valid keys for Blowfish...

Comment: To answer your question *`How long does it take to brute force Blowfish-448?`* we would need to know which scenario you are assuming… differently stated: what kind of hardware resources are you assuming a brute-forcer to have? Without that, all answers to your question can merely point out [what @SEJPM](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/43220/#comment98510_43220) already stated.